# Does NetBeans have C auto comment?

Tags: c++, c, netbeans

Does NetBeans have C auto comment?

I installed NetBeans IDE 7.2.1 and C/C++ Plugins.

When I type in "/**" and press Enter, it automatically generate some code like bellow.

```
/**
* @param param1
* @param param2
* @param param3
*/
```

I'm just wondering if I can modify what it generate.

I want to add more info like author, date, remark.

Simply saying, I want some comment to be generated when I type in "/**" and press Enter like bellow.
(The function is already defined.)

```
/**
* @author
* @date
* @param param1
* @param param2
* @param param3
* @remark
*/
void do_something( struct sturct_one *param1, int param2, char *param3 )
{
   ...
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Jan,

the NetBeans IDE documentation [section on adding source code documentation](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/navigating-editing.html) does not mention the possibility to customize the Doxygen template. So a short answer to your question

> *I'm just wondering if I can modify what it generate*

is: no, you can't.

Typically, one does not need any extras, e.g. the tags @author and @date from your example are unnecessary if you use a version control system. Did you considered using a CVS?

As an alternative solution (though not as elegant as typing '/**') you could use code templates. As described in the NetBeans [documentation](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/navigating-editing.html), you can define abbreviations for code templates. In your case you could define templates for Doxygen comments with @author, @date, @remark tags and 1, 2, 3, ... parameters, and use abbreviations 1, 2, ... to quickly insert the comments.